# Missing a ; after a for loop: Error found in JS Lint and with appendChild

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to remove a appendChild and keep getting the error -

SyntaxError: missing ; after for-loop initializer

I've never seen this error before. Here is the code that I have.

What is missing here?

```
var allChildren = document.getElementById("box").children;
    var moving = document.getElementById("box2");
    var newLocation = parseInt(moving.style.top, 0);
    var newLocation2 = parseInt(moving.style.left, 0);

    for (imageCheer); {
        if (newLocation2 = moving.style.left && newLocation = moving.style.top)
    {
         return x;
         allChildren.removeChild(list.childNodes[0]);
    }
    for (imageMarsh); { 
        if (newLocation2 = moving.style.left && newLocation = moving.style.top) 
    {
        return x; 
        allChildren.removeChild(list.childNodes[0]);
    }   

}
```

Comment: you should not use `for` loop in such manner: `for (imageCheer);`

Comment: `for (imageCheer);` { seems very strange :)

Comment: Oh. I'm wanting to pull up "each child", but don't think thats what I'm looking for.  I was assuming that it would be a for like for (each child) then the second statement that I'm pretty sure is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You for loops are syntactically incorrect. Typically they have the form `for (init; condition; step)`. EG `for (var i = 0; i< 10; i++)` . your loops are missing condition and step.

You also should remove the semicolon after `for();` because otherwise your loop body won't be executed.

And your loop bodies are wrong too. What do you want to achieve with `return x`? Consider if you use return inside a function, it will immediately stop the execution of the function, the remaining statements won't be executed.

Also consider that an equality check in JavaScript is done with `==` or even better `===`. A single `=` is an assignment.

And, finally you are missing some closing braces for the loop bodies.

Comment: I'm trying to do a collusion type of function, where if one image gets close to another, the image will disappear and will return, updating a sort of score like for a game. Theres a function for just the score in general. 

In general this is what I was thinking.  

for (each child) { 
  if (childs left = moving left && childs top = moving top) 
    {

    add to the score. 
   child will be removed
    }

}

Not sure if this what makes sense, but reading a book/trying to make a game up on my free-time is turning into a hassle more than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

I think `for (var i in imageCheer) {..}` would work

Comment: It certainly would, if imageCheer is an object. However, we don't even know what imageCheer is here.

Comment: var imageCheer = document.createElement("img");  for appendChild.